# intermodule dependencies in maven

Tags: java, maven

I want to build maven project having EJB module and WEB module, where EJB is needed in WEB module.

*parent pom.xml*

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>cz.literak.oauth</groupId>
<artifactId>OAuthLogin</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>OAuthLogin-web</module>
    <module>OAuthLogin-ejb</module>
</modules>
<name>OAuthLogin JEE Skeleton</name>
<url>http://www.literak.cz/OAuthLogin/</url>
```

*EJB pom.xml*

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>OAuthLogin</artifactId>
    <groupId>cz.literak.oauth</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>OAuthLoginEJB</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>
<name>OAuthLoginEJB Beans</name>
```

*WEB pom.xml*

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>OAuthLogin</artifactId>
    <groupId>cz.literak.oauth</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>OAuthLoginWEB</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>OAuthLogin Webapp</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cz.literak.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>OAuthLogin-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Intellij Idea tells me that version is unknown. When I run *mvn clean install* in parent module, it fails with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project OAuthLoginWEB: Could not resolve dependencies for project cz.literak.oauth:OAuthLoginWEB:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact cz.literak.oauth:OAuthLogin-ejb:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

Where is the issue? I browsed similar questions without luck. Thanks.

Comment: The OAuthLogin is of type 'ejb' and not 'jar'. So change the ´<type>ejb</type> and it should work. Furthermore you don't need to define a scope cause compile is the default. Apart from that it's best practice to define the version via `<version>${project.version}</version>´.

Comment: Unfortunatelly there is no difference after removing scope and changing type to ejb in dependency.

Comment: Is this a multi-module build? I assume it is...from where do you start ´mvn clean package´? From the war module ? (Check [here](https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee) for an example).

Comment: From parent module. Well, I will commit it to GitHub though it is not compilable yet, so you can take a look.

Comment: Really good idea...can you give a link on the project?

Comment: Reading is sometime a really good choice (sorry oversigth): You have defined the artifactId of your ejb module like this: ´<artifactId>OAuthLoginEJB</artifactId>´ and not ´<artifactId>OAuthLogin-ejb</artifactId>`.

Comment: There it is https://github.com/literakl/OAuthLogin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined the artifactId of your ejb module like this:

```
<artifactId>OAuthLoginEJB</artifactId>
```

**but not**

```
<artifactId>OAuthLogin-ejb</artifactId>
```

BUT YOUR DEPENDENCY is like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cz.literak.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>OAuthLogin-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Ooops, thanks, stupid error. Another good practice - name modules as their directories? :-)